# Ruby - Can Shoes GUI catch the wheel mouse?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, mousewheel, shoes

I'm trying to build a very simple vector drawing program. (In fact it's meant to be the base for others).
I've already implemented zooming and panning, but I'd like to do as it works in autocad for example, or sketchup.
That is, when you roll the wheel mouse, you zoom, and when you push it, you pan. (Actually this last feature is already working).
Problem is, how can I catch the wheel mouse with Shoes GUI for ruby?

Comment: Never used the library, haven't had the chance yet but there seems to be a `canvas` option which has the mouse scroll events https://github.com/shoes/shoes/blob/develop/lib/shoes.rb#L500

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think that the scroll there in canvas stands for scroll bar rather than for the mouse scroll events.

Answer (score 0):

For the very best of my knowledge, there is no such method. Tried searching the source etc.

However I took it as a [proposal for shoes4](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/issues/150) - please feel free to comment on the proposed DSL or just think of your own DSL - basically the way you'd want to use it because that's most likely the shoes way :-)

If I'm wrong and there is such a method, one of the guys in the shoes4 repo will know and I'll report back here.

Comment: Seems there's no such method. So it's really cool you posted it as a proposal for shoes4. At the DSL someone has already written one script which may work. Thank u. I'll surely write on the proposal